# Multiplication tables via maps in pointfree Haskell

Tags: haskell, pointfree

In Haskell I've defined a multiplication-table generator function like so:

```
multTable :: [[Int]]
multTable=map (\b -> map (b*) [1..12]) [1..12]
```

Which outputs...

```
[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
[2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24],
...[12,24,36,48,60,72,84,96,108,120,132,144]]
```

...and if you squint your eyes, this looks like multiplication tables for 1..12. So far so good ... now I've tried to make it point-free, thinking it should be pretty easy with composition. So I'm taking small steps and I believe that I've gotten partway there since I can do this:

```
map ($ 4) $ map (*) [1..12]
```

...which gives me:

```
[4,8,12,16,20,24,28,32,36,40,44,48]
```

Looking at this, the second map gives [a->a], which specifically here is a list of functions that multiply the values 1 through 12 by some number. The first map evaluates each of these functions providing them with the value 4, in turn producing the [4,8..] line.

I'm not necessarily expecting the pointfree version to be shorter, more concise or even more readable. As a Haskell newbie, I'm just looking to understand how it could be accomplished.

Comment: People new to Haskell seem to fall in love with point-free style. Love is blind; you'll grow out of it. Incidentally, here's a nice (not point-free) version: `[[x * y | x <- [1..12]] | y <- [1..12]]`.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson If he's having fun with it, why not let him? It's fun to see how far you can take some programming technique or concept. Whether or not it is ultimately practical, well, that doesn't necessarily matter.

Comment: Zeta's answer is instructive in the stepwise refinements that begin with my original and end in pointfree form. Daniel's answer has an appealing style that I find highly intuitive. Both answers are great. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a tool called [pointfree](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pointfree) on hackage, which helps you tremendously (see also [the wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pointfree)). It creates the following version:

```
multTable = map (flip map [1..12] . (*)) [1..12]
```

How do we get there? Well, lets move operators a little bit and try to apply `flip` on your function till we get something similar:

```
multTable = map (\b -> map (b*) [1..12])           [1..12] 
          = map (\b -> map ((*) b) [1..12])        [1..12] -- change to prefix notation
          = map (\b -> flip map [1..12] ((*) b)    [1..12] -- flip map
          = map (\b -> flip map [1..12] . (*) $ b) [1..12] -- associativity
          = map (flip map [1..12] . (*))           [1..12] -- eta-reduction
```

Note that we only need to focus on `\b -> map (b*) [1..12]`.

That being said, the pointfree version feels a little bit contrived. After all, you want a table, and [Benjamin's shows a rather nice way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28821283/multiplication-tables-via-maps-in-pointfree-haskell#comment45914449_28821283) to create one: list comprehensions:

```
multTable = [[x * y | x <- [1..12]] | y <- [1..12]]
```

This version is easier to read and more obvious to the reader, but then again, you probably thought that this would happen:

> I'm not necessarily expecting the pointfree version to be shorter, more concise or even more readable.

Comment: The `do` notation variant isn't as nice as the list comprehension: `do {x <- [1..12]; return $ do {y <- [1..12]; return $ x * y}}`. However, I'm way to tired to include it in a nice way in this answer, I'll probably add it tomorrow.

Comment: The "functor comprehension" version is particularly nice: `let for = flip fmap in for [1..12] $ \x -> for [1..12] $ \y -> x*y`. If you point-free-ify *that*, you get `for [1..12] $ for [1..12] . (*)` which looks quite pretty to me.

Comment: @DanielWagner: Do you want to add this as an answer? It really looks rather pretty.

Answer (score 3):

In a comment to Zeta's answer, he suggests this reimplementation of your code:

```
do
    x <- [1..12]
    return $ do
        y <- [1..12]
        return (x * y)
```

It's got sort of a pretty pattern to it, and desugars this way:

```
[1..12] >>= \x ->
return $ [1..12] >>= \y ->
         return (x * y)
```

Now it occurs to me that `m >>= \x -> return (f x)` is the same as `fmap f m`, so the above code really only needs `Functor` and not `Monad`. So this made me wonder what a "`do`-notation for functors" might look like, and how it would desugar. Defining `for = flip fmap`, here's how I think it might look desugared:

```
for [1..12] $ \x ->
for [1..12] $ \y ->
x*y
```

(Hopefully you can see the parallels with the desugared `do`-notation.) In any case, pointfree-ifying this gives something quite pretty:

```
for [1..12] $ for [1..12] . (*)
```

Comment: I accidentally omitted the 'f' in `fmap`  and it still worked with the rest of the expression you provided. This `flip` of `map` (or `fmap`) as `for` makes a lot of sense to me coming from an imperative background. This was an extremely interesting insight.

Comment: @devgeezer Yep, for lists, `fmap = map`. Glad you enjoyed it.